# Which smart contract has the most token supply?

Tags: tokens, totalsupply

I have found smart contracts whose total token supply is 10,000, but I know the token supply can go beyond 10K.

Which of all smart contracts, as of today, has the highest token supply count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some really high, like trillions. Safemoon, shibe. But according to the erc20 standard, total supply is managed with a uint256, so the theoretical maximum supply of a token would be 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935, if it used 0 decimals.

And if one with that supply doesn't exist, it would take like 5 minutes for someone to deploy a token to the network and mint themselves the total supply at that value.